# How I can do a group by year in hibernate using criteria?

Tags: sql, linq, hibernate

How I can do a group by year in hibernate using criteria?
For example in this query:

```
session.CreateCriteria("Sample").SetProjection
                (
                  Projections.ProjectionList()
                 .Add(Projections.Property("SampleDate"), "Name")
                 .Add(Projections.Max("H2"))                 
                 .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("SampleDate"))
                ).List();
```

Comment: I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067363/group-by-month-with-criteria-in-hibernate